# Why does the interaction between model, view and contoller look different?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im new to ASP.NET MVC, trying to learn the basics.
Im now trying to learn the relationship between the model ,view and controller.

The interaction between these three looks different, why? (Look at the arrows)

Source 1:  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28v=vs.100%29)

Source 2 (Page 65): [Steven Sanderson](http://books.google.se/books?id=M2BLtR7oNcQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=sv&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I would be glad if you help me sort out my confusion

Thanks

Edit:
What you are saying is that mvc can be implemented differently?
(Still asking about asp.net mvc - Not mvc in general)

I have been looking at the [mvcmusicstore](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)
and it looks like this.
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);
        return View(album);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

view:
(Had to add as image, add code the normal way did not work)
[image: The view]

This looks like the MSDN version, how would this be rewritten to fit Sandersons diagram?
Maybe this will help me understand!

Edit again:

Hi again

Let me sum this up. Please respond if I'm wrong.
The way Microsoft intended us to use mvc is the one we see in the above MSDN link and in MusicStore.
Then there are other "versions" of mvc such as Sandersons (or whereever it originates from).
So Microsoft give us a basic way of how to use the mvc framework, but it is ok to do it other ways.

A newbie should not get stressed by seeing different versions, sticking to the one seen in MSDN/MusicStore is perfectly fine.

Comment: Per your edit, I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is the inclusion of the "Presentation Model" in Sanderson's diagram.  The ASP.NET MVC implementation often uses the Model as the Presentation Model, even though they can be different (and I would argue that they should be different, but it's a holy war and there's no need to get into that).

In most very simple ASP.NET MVC applications, the model is the data entity.  Whether it's an EF entity or a Linq2Sql entity, makes no difference.  This is because most applications are simple forms-over-data and the presentation is probably one-to-one with the persistence.

The MVC pattern itself, however, doesn't require this.  In a more pure framework-agnostic form, Sanderson's diagram illustrates the fact that the controller is interacting with the model.  The model is really the "gateway to the domain core" in this sense.  Controllers and views are part of the application, but the model has the underlying business logic and, beneath that, layers of persistence and other infrastructure information (properly separated, of course) which are unknown to the application.  The boundary between the controller and the model is the application boundary, the point at which other applications can also connect to the domain core and interact with it.

A presentation model is usually nothing more than a simple value object.  It's not an entity of any kind in the sense that it doesn't have to exhibit any business behavior or maintain its lifecycle the way that a persistable business entity would.  It's just a flat object with some attributes of data.

It can have *some* behavior, but that behavior is for the application and not for the domain core.  For example, maybe it has some methods or properties that the view can use.  The presentation model is part of the application, so it's presentation-layer-aware.  Essentially it just holds data that the controller needs to pass to the view (or even receive from the request, depending on the framework).

In ASP.NET MVC you'll very often see the model used also as the presentation model.  The same object may be playing two roles in those cases, but the two roles are definitely different.

---

**Edit:** Just noticed your updated question...

In that example, `Album` is playing the role of both domain model and presentation model.  (In fact, I would argue that it's not a domain model at all because it's too anemic.  Notice that it has no functionality, just bare data.)  In a richer domain model, `Album` would likely have more functionality.  For a contrived example, imagine that instead of auto-implemented properties it has properties which enforce business logic when set, and it has methods on it such as `AddSong(Song song)` and `Play()` and other such behaviors.

This richer model can still be used as a presentation model, but the functionality might not make sense in the scope of a view.  A view is really suited more toward just bare data elements.  The controller would interact with the model's functionality.  So you might create a presentation model similar to the `Album` domain model in structure, and it would look just like the one in your example.

Going forward, what if the view needs other data as well?  Maybe the view needs to know something about other models which aren't part of the same aggregate as `Album`.  It wouldn't make sense to modify the domain models to accommodate the view.  That's backwards.  The presentation should wrap around the domain core, not the other way around.  So you might add properties to the presentation model which are populated from other things inside the controller.

So you might end up with something like this...

Domain model:

```
public class Album
{
    public int ID { get; private set; } // might need to be immutable

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            // don't allow empty titles
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Title");
            _title = value;
        }
    }

    private Album() { }
    public Album(int id, string title)
    {
        ID = id;
        Title = title;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        // some implementation
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

As the business domain grows and changes, this model could change with it.  The main point is that it changes at the behest of the domain core and the business logic, *not* at the behest of UI implementations.

A particular "page" on a particular website which uses this domain core may need specific information about an album, and maybe some other information as well.  You'd tailor a presentation model to fit that:

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Listener> Listeners { get; set; }
    public string SomeCompletelyUnrelatedValueNeededByTheView { get; set; }
}
```

The controller would then construct this presentation model for the view:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    // TODO: validate and sanitize any inputs

    var album = AlbumRepository.Get(id); // after all, why bind the UI _directly_ to the DB?  that's just silly
    var someOtherObject = SomeOtherRepository.Get(someOtherValueFromSomewhereElse);

    var albumVM = new AlbumViewModel
    {
        ID = album.ID,
        Title = album.Title,
        Owner = somethingElse.SomeValue,
        Listeners = someOtherObject.GetListeners(album),
        SomeCompletelyUnrelatedValueNeededByTheView = "foo"
    };

    return View(albumVM);
}
```

This is a much more manual approach overall.  It's useful when you have more complex domain models, multiple complex applications interacting with that domain, different technology stacks throughout the domain, etc.  For simple forms-over-data applications the standard ASP.NET MVC implementation usually works fine.  Most of the tutorials for it reflect this, consolidating multiple responsibilities into fewer objects, using decorators instead of explicit code (assuming the use of the same stack of tools across the board), etc.

The examples you're looking at get you to a working application very quickly with very little code.  As with any framework, it works beautifully if you do things the way the framework intends you to do them.  If you *need* to step outside the bounds of the framework, you can still maintain the pattern in a more abstract and framework-agnostic way.

---

**Edit:** For your update again...

In a way, yes.  ASP.NET MVC is a framework which borrows a lot from the MVC pattern in general.  As with all things, there's more than one way to do it.  Sticking with simple implementations and quick applications, the functionality provided by the ASP.NET MVC framework and explained in its various tutorials is perfectly acceptable and is a great example of the use of a framework... Using a tool to get a job done.

They stick to the pattern in all the most meaningful ways.  At the same time, however, in the true nature of a framework (which is generally outside the scope of a pattern description), they try to give you tools which make very light work of the actual development.  If you don't have a pressing need to separate your domain models from your presentation models, you don't have to.  One model can play both roles.  If you don't have a pressing need to abstract your data access behind, say, a repository pattern, you don't have to.  You can throw together some quick Entity Framework functionality directly in your Models and be done with it.

Ultimately it's up to the needs of the project, the preferences of the developer(s), and so on.  The patterns are more academic, the frameworks are more pragmatic.  Balancing the two is the key.

Comment: Hi again David. I have made a small update. Please have a look.

Comment: @CliffSmith: Updated.  This may be my longest Stack Overflow answer yet :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you have set a new record =)
Thank you very much for your commitment. (And to the others aswell)
I think I have control over my confusion now.
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I guess the distinction is that in asp.net MVC you can have strongly typed views which have 'knowledge' of your model and the entity being passed through to the view. In its purest sense though the View shouldn't (or rather, neednt) have any knowledge of the model. For that reason I say Steven Sandersons example is better.

Fantastic book by he way!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't sweat it - Stephen Sanderson's diagram is showing less of the cycle but in more detail.

I'd interpret the MS article arrows as:

- Controller populates model (from services, etc)
- Controller directs to view
- View populates through binding model

The microsoft diagram isn't really that useful or informative or useful though in my opinion.  You could equally argue that arrows could go in different directions - or even in both directions like Sanderson's do.   E.g. Controller also received models from binding, etc.

The Sanderson arrows are annotated well and are self-explicit, and the book is great.